# embedding diagram for a 2-dimensional slice

Tags: graphics3d

Any idea how to draw this diagram? It is an illustration of the embedding diagram for a 2-dimensional slice through the initial data of a cosmology, containing 6 black holes. The central sphere is the cosmological region that contains the black holes, and the asymptotically flat regions are the flanges that occur on the other side of the black hole’s MOTS (again shown as thick black bands).[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you look on the website for possible similar solutions?

Comment: In general, nothing similar in the web. Let me know if have an idea.

Comment: Here's and idea: [How to plot a hole in a hole in a hole?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2167301/how-to-plot-a-hole-in-a-hole-in-a-hole/2167479#2167479)

Comment: @Kuba, thank you for the link. This is certainly something to start. However, my question is more challenging, and I will be grateful for help.

Comment: Do you have equations for this?

Comment: @Vitaliy, not actually equations. But there is a initial data, time-symmetry imposed on constraint equations. Description of a diagram is in my question. The central sphere contains 6-black holes (shown as thick black bands) connected to asymptotically flat regions.